# Tool for graphing packet size distribution on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, packet-analyzer, graph

Is there a tool for Linux to easily produce graphs (histograms) of the packet sizes (e.g. TCP) of network traffic ?

(before I start putting together something using e.g. matplotlib and python bindings for libpcap, I'd better ask here...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/overview.html) reports a packet size histogram, among many other things.